# Chrome Extension: It is not showing the popup and cannot removeRules as in the example

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my `background.js` I had to comment out the second line casue it keept giving error on `undefined` I'm following the example here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted the problem is that the popup is never visible, if I hoover the icon it say that the extension has access to that website (or doesn't if I'm in another one) but other than that it is not displaying the relative popup in `page_action` also the icon looks to be colored all the time, and doesn't shift to grayscale/color depending on the tab/page being loaded.

```
  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostEquals: '*://ansa.it/*'},
        })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
  });
```

This is my `page_action` portion:

```
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/apple-32px.png",
    "default_title": "Apple Test",
    "default_popup": "popup/default1.html"
  }
```

**edit**: the undefined error was resolved by adding `declarativeContent` in permission so I uncommented the code, but the problem persist, the icon is being colored also while on stackoverflow.com or any other non `chrome://` tab

Comment: Now your problem is different: it's a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1127067). A workaround is to 1) make a gray icon manually and specify it in `default_icon`, 2) add [SetIcon](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-SetIcon) action with the colored icon before ShowPageAction action.

Comment: @wOxxOm and it looks quite old too!